# Why does 'EEUU' stand for USA?

Tags: abreviaturas, siglas

I was again wondering about acronyms in Spanish - particularly EEUU.

'EU' itself should represent 'Estados Unidos'. But why are there 2 Es and 2 Us? It's confusing to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spanish using a letter twice in an acronym means that that word is plural.

EE. UU. = Estados Unidos. If it were E.U., it would mean "Estado Unido"*.

Other examples are:

RR. HH. = Recursos Humanos (Human Resources).

ss. = siguientes

HH. = Honorables

*It's a rule not everybody follows and nowadays you can find people who write "E.U." in newspapers and other media.